# Django inlineformset_factory with custom forms

Tags: django, forms, inline-formset, django-crispy-forms

There are two classes in model, Node and Host. The Node has foreign key to the host.
I have to make a crispy form, which creates a Node (and the Node needs a Host, so creates a Host too). The form have to be a bit fancy ( helper.layout={ ...fancy stuff...'field'... }, as I know ).

So I created NodeCreateForm, HostCreateForm - from forms.ModelForm, with helper.layout

NodeFormSet=inlineformset_factory(Host,Node,extra = 1)

in view, in the NodeCreate class, I have a HostCreateForm, and a NodeFormSet, 
I set the NodeFormset instance to the HostCreateForm

on the html, the HostCreateForm shows up good, but the Node isn't formed at all.
I changed the NodeFormset to inlineformset_factory(Host,Node, form = NodeCreateForm ,extra = 1), but nothing really happens.

the code:
http://pastebin.com/FTLEHvNF

I haven't got too much experience in Django, so I'm not sure, this is the good way...

Comment: Working on something similar just now. I've nearly cracked it and will post my code when it's working. I can't see your code because pastebin is blocked by my office IT policy.